# Hide two button out of three using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in jquery . But I need some help . I want to hide and show the button in jquery.

I have 3 Button but I want to show only one button when I click one than other 2 button hide .

```css
   input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .custom-file-upload {
 background:#edeef0;
 color: #2b2c31;
 font-size:18px;
 width:170px;
 padding:12px;
  
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 
 border:1px solid #fff;
 cursor:pointer;
 }
 
 .social_button_area{
 
 width:130px;
 padding:10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 border:1px solid #fff;
 
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 
 height:52px;
 cursor:pointer;
 background:#edeef0;
 color: #2b2c31;
 
 }
 
 
 .social_text_area{
 width: 100%;
 height:120px;
 border:1px solid #fff;
 color: #0f366b;
 resize: none;
 }
 
 #musicinfo {
  display: none;
 }
 
 #audioinfo {
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
    <div align="center">

  <form name="fileField" action="story_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
    <div class="top_attach_sub top_attach_sub_mobile" align="right">
     <div align="right">

      
       <div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
       <button id="Flow" name="Submit" type="submit" class="social_button_area" title=" Share Your Flow ">
       <i class="fa fa-share-alt-square"></i> Flow
       </button>
       
       </div>
      
       <div style="float:right; padding:5px;">

       <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
       <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Upload Photo
       </label>
       <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="photo"/>
       </div>
       
       
       <div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
       <button id="audio" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Add Audio ">
       <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> Add Audio
       </button>
       </div>
       
       
       <div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
       <button id="music" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Add Video ">
       <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i> Add Video
       </button>
       </div>


     </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>

    </div>
    
     <div class="small-12 columns"> 
     
      <div class="top_attach_sub" align="center" style="height:130px; width:100%;">
       <textarea name="dessc" class="social_text_area" placeholder="Flow your thinking"></textarea>
      </div>
     
     </div>
     
     
     
     <div id="audioinfo" class="audio_mobile">
     
     <div class="small-12 columns"> 
     
      <div class="top_attach_sub" align="center" style="height:50px; width:100%;">
       <input name="c_aud" type="text" class="social_text_area" value="" placeholder="Enter Clyp Audio Url. Example : https://clyp.it/e1bn0tsz ">
      </div>
      
      <div align="center" style="background:#FFFFFF;">
       <p class="help" style="padding:5px;">
       1. Login your Clyp Account . or  <a href="https://clyp.it/#signup" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
       </br>
       2. Upload Your Audio Song using upload button .
       </br>
       3. Choose Your Audio FIle than Wait for upload 
       </br>
       4. After upload fill up the basic Title and Description of this audio.
       </br>
       5. Than click Save.
       </br>
       6. Copy the url of the song . <storng>(Example : https://clyp.it/eosdmbmg)</storng> from the address bar of your browser.
       </br>
       7. Copy the url and paste the below text field.Thanks.
       </p>
      </div>
     
     </div>
     
     </div>
     
     
     <div id="musicinfo">
     
     <div class="small-12 columns"> 
     
      <div class="top_attach_sub" align="center" style="height:50px; width:100%;">
       <input name="y_vid" type="text" class="social_text_area" value="" placeholder="Enter Youtube Video Url. Example : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeIXjV0LWnA ">
      </div>
      
      <div align="center" style="background:#FFFFFF;">
       <p class="help" style="padding:5px;">
       1. Go to Youtube . or  <a href="https://youtube.com" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
       </br>
       2. Open a video which you want to share our flow.
       </br>
       3. Copy the youtube url.
       </br>
       4. Paste it into the box.
       </br>
       5. Than Press flow.
       </br>
       
       </p>
      </div>
     
     </div>
     
     </div>
    
    </div>
    </div>
    
    </form>

    </div>
```

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

    $('button,input[type="file"]').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.tagName=='INPUT')
    $('button,input[type="file"]').not($(this)).toggle();
    else{
    $('button').not($(this)).toggle();
    $('input[type="file"]').closest('div').toggle();
    }
    });



    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#file-upload").on('change',function(){
    //do whatever you want
    alert("Photo Selected.");
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(
    function() {
    $("#music").click(function() {
    $("#musicinfo").fadeToggle();
    });
    });

    $(document).ready(
    function() {
    $("#audio").click(function() {
    $("#audioinfo").fadeToggle();
    });
    });

    </script>
```

Firtly , SHow all the three button after that ,

1. If click Upload Photo

   Hide : Add Video and Add Audio
2. If Click Add Video

   Hide : Upload Photo and Add Audio
3. If Click Add Audio 
   Hide : Upload Photo and Add Video

But the flow button never hide because its the post button .

Thanks to all .

Comment: i see two button ..

Comment: @scaisEdge maybe OP refers to the file input as button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.toggle()` method in combination with `.not()` method.

```js
$('button[type="button"],input[type="file"]').click(function(e){
   if(e.target.tagName=='INPUT')
      $('button,input[type="file"]').not($(this)).not($('button[type="submit"]')).toggle();
   else{
      $('button').not($(this)).not($('button[type="submit"]')).toggle();
      $('input[type="file"]').closest('div').toggle();
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">

<div style="float:right; padding:5px;">

<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
<i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Upload Photo
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file" name="photo"/>
</div>


<div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
<button id="audio" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Add Audio ">
<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> Add Audio
</button>
</div>


<div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
<button id="music" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Add Video ">
<i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i> Add Video
</button>
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @SaifulIslamSagor replace the selectors with my suggestion `$('button, input')` The only problem you will have is the `<label>` **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/u04jcegr/ unless you give those elements a class name... then you could just target the class name in the selector.

Comment: Firtly , SHow all the three button after that ,

If click Upload Photo

Hide : Add Video and Add Audio
If Click Add Video

Hide : Upload Photo and Add Audio
If Click Add Audio Hide : Upload Photo and Add Video

Comment: @SaifulIslamSagor My example does exactly that.... not sure why you keep pasting the *"Firthly" comment into everything.

Comment: yes its good to see but I need some more I want when the active button is clicked than again all the three button show .

Comment: I need so more help when I used it than the text box is not show .

Comment: yes its work but I use the text area with tinymce but the tinymce editor not showing when the button click and the Flow button never hide because its the submit button . thank you so much for helping me and this is the last update I need sir thanks .

Comment: @Alexandru-Ionut Mihai  Hellow Sir I need last update please

Comment: OKK sir button problem solved but I use tinymce that why the textarea all top tinymce button are hide . i want to see the button of tinymce. thanks

Comment: You must use another `.not()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if this worked:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#active").hide();

  $(".custom-file-upload").click(function() {
    $("#audio").hide();
    $("#music").hide();
    $("#active").show();
  });
  $("#audio").click(function() {
    $(".custom-file-upload").hide();
    $("#music").hide();
    $("#active").show();
  });
  $("#music").click(function() {
    $("#audio").hide();
    $(".custom-file-upload").hide();
    $("#active").show();
  });
  $("#active").click(function() {
    $("#audio").show();
    $(".custom-file-upload").show();
    $("#music").show();
    $("#active").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
        input[type="file"]
        {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .custom-file-upload
        {
            background: #edeef0;
            color: #2b2c31;
            font-size: 18px;
            width: 170px;
            padding: 12px;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .social_button_area
        {
            width: 130px;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            height: 52px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: #edeef0;
            color: #2b2c31;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div align="center">
  <div style="float: right; padding: 5px;">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i>Upload Photo
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="photo" />
  </div>
  <div style="float: right; padding: 5px;">
    <button id="audio" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Add Audio ">
      <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>Add Audio
    </button>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right; padding: 5px;">
    <button id="music" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Add Video ">
      <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>Add Video
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
  <div style="float: right; padding: 5px;">
    <button id="active" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Show All Buttons!!! ">
      <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>Active
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firtly , SHow all the three button after that ,

If click Upload Photo

Hide : Add Video and Add Audio
If Click Add Video

Hide : Upload Photo and Add Audio
If Click Add Audio Hide : Upload Photo and Add Video

Comment: yes its good to see but I need some more I want when the active button is clicked than again all the three button show

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you wanted.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.social_button_area, .custom-file-upload').click(function()
  {
    $('.social_button_area, .custom-file-upload').not(this).hide();
  })
});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
background:#edeef0;
color: #2b2c31;
font-size:18px;
width:170px;
padding:12px;

-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;

border:1px solid #fff;
cursor:pointer;
}

.social_button_area{

width:130px;
padding:10px;
font-size: 18px;
border:1px solid #fff;

-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;

height:52px;
cursor:pointer;
background:#edeef0;
color: #2b2c31;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center">

   <div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
      <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Upload Photo
    </label>
    <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="photo"/>
   </div>


    <div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
      <button id="audio" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Add Audio ">
        <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i> Add Audio
      </button>
    </div>


    <div style="float:right; padding:5px;">
      <button id="music" name="Submit" type="button" class="social_button_area" title=" Add Video ">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i> Add Video
      </button>
    </div>

</div>
```